# Show delete message URL based on username

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have an PHP + Jquery wall message that show all message from anybody. Now I want to set delete URL in every messages. But the rule, user can't see delete url if the messages is not his own.

```
.childs {
opacity: 0;
color: #000;
margin-left: 10px;
float: right;
}

.childs:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: pointer;
}

.parents:hover > .childs {
opacity: 1.0;
}
```

--
This logged in as Greg

```
<section class="parents">
Greg : Today is holiday
<div class="childs"><a href="delete.php">Delete</a></div>
```

This logged in as Jeremy

```
<section class="parents">
Jeremy : Beautiful day
<div class="childs"><a href="delete.php">Delete</a></div>
```

I want the Delete link show based on username logged in. So if Jeremy mouse over Greg message, delete link will not show because it's not his message and if Greg mouse over his own message, he can see the delete url link and can delete it.

So how can I set that ?
Thanks for helps.

Comment: Your delete option should only render if your session token matches a given user. Otherwise you wouldnt render out the option. Also you should have this check on the delete.php as well. You shouldnt need anything with css or js

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach. Store the logged in information of session using `$_SESSION`then compare this on your view class/code.

Like

```
<div class="childs">
<?php
if($_SESSION['logged_in_user'] == true) { 
   echo "<a href='delete.php'>Delete</a></div>";
}?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used the SESSION variable for the logged in username and compare it with the message owner. If it is the same owner, echo the delete div.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['username'] == $comment_owner){
    echo '<div class="childs"><a href="delete.php">Delete</a></div>';
}
?>
```

This is the easiest way to do this but quite messy.